# do I have to install npm for every new project?

Tags: javascript, npm-install

I have NPM installed in my PC how to use it for a new project?

or do I have to install npm for every new project?

Comment: What do you mean? Install it as in getting the npm executable or as in running `npm install`?

Comment: Use npm init to create a new project, and npm install for an existing project that already has it&#39;s dependancy written in its package.json

Your question was answered for sure in stackoverflow, please search the next time

Comment: I mean do i have to right in git `npm install` in every new project? or there is a command to initialise it

Comment: `npm install` does *not* install npm ... but rather the modules required for the module

Comment: @JonasWilms I think you meant "the modules required for the project" or something along those lines. Although I guess it might also be a joke about it being modules all the way down. :P

Answer (score 3):

NPM is extremely useful, but, when you install it, you install it globally. It comes with Node JS, so when you install Node JS, you should have npm installed(type npm -v to see the version and whether npm is installed).


"npm init" creates a package.json for your folder, which contains all the information about the version number, the name of the project, and some other information. In package.json, you can add dependencies, which basically say your project relies on that npm package.


"npm install" will install all the packages specified in package.json, and, if you want to install something specific, you would type "npm install ".

Answer (score 0):

No Need to Install npm for Every Project

npm comes bundled with Node.js, so if you have Node.js installed, you automatically have npm. You only need to install Node.js once for npm functionality across all your projects.